# Is it possible to append only the newly created/arrived blob in Azure blob storage to the Azure SQL DB?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

Here is my problem in steps:

1. Uploading specific csv file via PowerShell with Az module to a specific Azure blob container. [Done, works fine]
2. There is a trigger against this container which fires when a new file appears.  [Done, works fine]
3. There is a pipeline connected with this trigger, which is appends the fresh csv to the specific SQL table. [Done, but not good]

I have a problem with step 3. I don't want to append all the csv-s within the container(how is's working now), I just want to append the csv which is just arrived - the newest in the container.

**Okay, the solution is:**

1. **there is a builtin attribute in pipeline called @triggerBody().fileName**
2. **Since I have the file which fired the trigger, I can pass it to the Pipeline.**

Comment: Please share with us your pipeline so we could improve what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use event trigger and check Blob created option.

[image]

Here is an official documentation about it. You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger).